# Django-CMS multi-regional and multilingual subsite

Tags: django, multilingual, django-cms, django-sites

We have to create multi-regional and multilingual web site. For example:

- http://mysite.com/jp/us/    For Japan in English
- http://mysite.com/jp/jp/    For Japan in Japanese
- http://mysite.com/au/us/    For Australia in English

For multiligual, **django-cms** and **i18n_patterns** handle it very well. But when I try to use django sites framework to add multi-regional support, it doesnot work as expected :(. I add site with subdomain: mysite.com/au , mysite.com/vn, mysite.com/us. In django-cms admin page I add content to site already. But now I don't know how to config url to match the site.

And I want to have `http://mysite.com/<region>/<language>/` but **i18n_patterns** seem to force url like `http://mysite.com/<language>/<region>/`. How to change this also

Please help

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how flexible you are with your URL scheme, but how about this:

Use the standard django CMS i18n URL rules (so you end up with yoursite.com/ja/ and yoursite.com/en/).

Next create two pages: 'au' and 'jp'. Redirect the homepage to one of the two pages (or write some smarter logic for that, for example in a middleware). Now keep your regional content in those two sub trees.

Simply don't translate the pages in the 'au' subtree into Japanese if you don't want.

Comment: Your solution seem easier to implement, but then we have to change url to <language>/<region> and it somehow not what they asked. Thank your your solution.

Comment: So changing that requirement is not an option? How will the two regions differ?

Comment: That's client reequirement :( I think I must write a middleware to handle this. Thankyou anyway

Comment: Don't forget that a middleware won't suffice. You also need something like i18n_patterns to make reverse work. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, middleware and custom i18n_patterns as well :(

Comment: your client should read iso standards and change his mind imho

Answer (score 1):

You may make it, by writing your own copy of `i18n_patterns`.

So by definition:

> **Language prefix in URL patterns**
>
> ```
> i18n_patterns(*urls, prefix_default_language=True)[source]
> ```
>
> This function can be used in a root URLconf and Django will
>   automatically prepend the current active language code to all URL
>   patterns defined within i18n_patterns().

Here an example made inside template but same variables/objects you need in your implementation.

> **Reversing in templates**
>
> If localized URLs get reversed in templates they always use the
>   current language. To link to a URL in another language use the
>   language template tag. It enables the given language in the enclosed
>   template section:
>
> ```
> {% load i18n %}
>
> {% get_available_languages as languages %}
>
> {% trans "View this category in:" %}
> {% for lang_code, lang_name in languages %}
>     {% language lang_code %}
>     <a href="{% url 'category' slug=category.slug %}">{{ lang_name }}</a>
>     {% endlanguage %}
> {% endfor %}
> ```
>
> The language tag expects the language code as the only argument.

**Reference:** [Django docs - i18n/translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/)